# Redux toolkit not checking the rejected case

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am new to redux toolkit, My objective is to not let the dashboard to render if the user who is trying to login is not a registered member. I am sending a 500 error from the backend if the username or password is invalid which works fine. The extraReducers is not going to rejected case even if the api response is 500 instead it goes to the fulfilled case.My expectation was that if the api gives an error, it will go to the rejected case. Below is my slice,

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

export const currentUser = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");

const initialState = {
  currentUser: currentUser
    ? currentUser
    : {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        name: "",
        pic: "",
        confirmPassword: "",
      },
  status: null,
  isLoggedIn: currentUser ? true : false,
  userInfoFromStorage: "",
};

//login action
export const authUser = createAsyncThunk("users/authUser", async (data) => {
  const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:3010/api/users/login", data);
  return res.data;
});

//register action
export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "users/registerUser",
  async (data) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:3010/api/users", data);
      console.log(res);
      return res.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
);

const userReducer = createSlice({
  name: "user", //to identify the slice
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logoutUser: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
      localStorage.removeItem("userInfo");
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(authUser.pending, (state) => {
      console.log("pending");
      state.status = "pending";
    });
    builder.addCase(authUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "success";
      state.isLoggedIn = true;
      state.currentUser = action.payload;
      state.userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.setItem(
        "userInfo",
        JSON.stringify(action.payload)
      );
    });
    builder.addCase(authUser.rejected, (state) => {
      console.log("failed")
      state.status = "failed";
      state.isLoggedIn = false;
    });
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { logoutUser } = userReducer.actions;

export default userReducer.reducer;
```

dispatching action below from loginPage

```
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(authUser({ email: email, password: password }));
    // history.push("/myNotes");
  };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your thunk, you are manually handling the error. There is no way that any other code after that could know that something went wrong.

You have three options here:

- do not `try..catch` in your `createAsyncThunk` call. The error will be cleaned up from non-standard fields and end up in `action.error` of the rejected action
- manually `throw` something. The error will be cleaned up from non-standard fields and end up in `action.error` of the rejected action
- manually return `thunkApi.rejectWithValue(yourError)`. The error will not be cleaned up and land in `action.payload` of the rejected action.

What you are doing now (handling the error and returning nothing) is essentially equal to doing `return undefined` in your function - which will end up as a fulfilled action with `undefined` as payload.